# How to get the prev/next element in class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to to fadeOut the previous and the next class of a specific one, why my code isnt working? You know the solution?

**Note: How to specify that the previous of #homebut is #aboutus, and that the next of#aboutus is #homebut?**

Thanks a lot for any help!

This is my html-code:

```
<body>
    <div class="menuEintraege" id="2">
      <li class="current"><a href="home.html" id="homebut">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="apps.html"id="appsbut">apps</a></li>
        <li><a href="hedone.html" id="hedonebut">hedone</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" id="contactbut">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html" id="aboutusbut">about us</a></li>
    </div>
</body>
```

and this my javascript till now:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).prev("li").fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).next("li").fadeOut("fast");
}
```

Comment: You realise that your HTML is invalid? A `li` element may only be contained within a `ul` or `ol`; nothing else. And if you just forgot to add in the `ul`/`ol` element, please note that the *only* valid child of either of those elements is the `li`; so the `div` shouldn't ever be a sibling to an `li`.

Comment: Why you place `<li>`s inside `<div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thoughts, would be:

```
$('li a:first').addClass('active');

$('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = this,
        $that = $(that),
        aEls = $('.menuEintraege a'),
        aActive = $('.menuEintraege a.active')
        .closest('li')
        .index();
    if (that.id == 'pre') {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        var pre = aEls.eq(aActive - 1);
        var prev = pre.length ? pre : aEls.last();
        prev.addClass('active');
    }
    else if (that.id == 'nxt') {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        var pre = aEls.eq(aActive + 1);
        var prev = pre.length ? pre : aEls.first();
        prev.addClass('active');
    }
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PJKF4/).

Comment: this code jsut clashes with the rest of my code. whats happens here? aEls.eq(aActive - 1)

Comment: That finds the element from the `aEls` array at the index point identified by that expression (the index of the current element minus 1).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().prev("li").fadeOut("fast");
    $(this).parent().next("li").fadeOut("fast");
}
```

Comment: That doesn't get #homebut `for $("#aboutusbut").next()`

Comment: why this alert($(this).parent().next("li").attr("id")); just show an popup with "undefined"?